# ¿How can I get around this "undeclared" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This isn't too general, so I can't quite condense it under the title, but here is my problem. I'm using Tkinter to create a very simply UI to select an option, confirm the option with a button, and then the button will forget the labels in order to update them and pack them again. It looks like this

```
from tkinter import ttk

class window(ttk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, master):
           super().__init__(master)

           self.option1 = ttk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option")
           self.option2 = ttk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option")
           self.button = ttk.Button(master,text="Confirm",command=Next())
           self.option1.pack(side="top")
           self.option2.pack(side="top")
           self.button.pack(side="top")


           def Next():
                 self.option1.pack_forget()
                 self.button.pack_forget()
    ...
```

My problems occur because since this button has to use the `Next()` function, it'll tell me that I can't use it because it isn't declared yet, and if declare the button underneath the function, it'll tell me the button isn't declared yet. I tried declaring it without defining the command beforehand and after it'd read the `Next()`function I'd declare it again this time writing that the button's command should be `Next()`, but the button doesn't seem to suffer the change as pressing it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Your indentation is off, can you fix it?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This code can't possibly work as written, even with fixed indentation. Tk is provided by `Tkinter` only on Python 2 (it's `tkinter` on Python 3). But no-arg `super()` is Python 3 only. Please provide an actual [MCVE] and tag your question with python-3.x or python-2.x to indicate which version it's supposed to work with.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "undeclared" error. In any case, your indentation is totally wrong, and a key part of python, so you have to fix it to reflect your actual use-case. Finally, please always provide a [mcve]. Finally, I'm fairly certain you are running into basic stumbling blocks with writing python class definitions, did you do *any* research to see what might be the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: Lets not close this... the problem is reasonably clear. May be a good duplicate though.

Comment: Well, my Tab key forced me into the next text field instead of adding spaces so I'll fix the example in a second. Outside of the obviously malfunction in the indentation in the example that I can't be dumb enough to notice when UI tells you what's wrong to start with, like I explained, the error occurs because I need to declare the function before my button, but if I do, my function needs me to declare the button. While I did look up other solutions, it stumbled into a couple of other problems so I thought I'd ask for the core of it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you called `Next()` during the definition of the class. You should simply assign `self.Next`. The button will be created when you instantiate the class. Notice that `Next` is an instance method and needs a `self` parameter also

```
from Tkinter import ttk

class window(ttk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, master):
         super().__init__(master)

        self.option1 = ttk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option")
        self.option2 = ttk.Radiobutton(master, text="Option")
        self.button = ttk.Button(master, text="Confirm", command=self.Next)
        self.option1.pack(side="top")
        self.option2.pack(side="top")
        self.button.pack(side="top")


    def Next(self):
        self.option1.pack_forget()
        self.button.pack_forget()
```

Comment: I think that explains why a similar approach I had with a previous project worked despite having pretty much the same structure on the order I declared functions and other objects, but for some reason I decided to omitt both ```self```'s. I'll try it out when I'm at my PC again.